# Express error when trying to send static file: path must be absolute

Tags: express, heroku

I have this code that works fine locally, but when running in Heroku I get an error

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var path = require('path')
app.use(express.static('public'));
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
const portNum = 8080
var port = process.env.PORT || portNum;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html')
})
```

however when running in heroku I get the error:

`TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the absolute path using:

```
path.join(__dirname, myfilename)
```

Reference - https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

Comment: my friend also has the same code as me but doesn't get that error on heroku in his app

Comment: I am not sure about the configurations you guys did on heroku. So I really can't answer this but using __dirname would solve the issue for you.

Comment: ok thx, but I can't really see why this would work locally and not on Heroku